# Catch react component error in unit tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Not able to test a react component throwing some error.

1. Normal throw from function gets caught (Test Passes)
2. Same throw in React does not get caught (Test Fails)

```
// react.js
function Test() {
    if (true)
        throw `Err msg`;
    return <div> abc </div>;
}
```

```
// react.spec.js
it('throws Error', () => {
    expect(() => {
        Test();
    }).toThrow('Err msg');
});

it('throws Error from react', () => {
    expect(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, HtmlContainer);
    }).toThrow('Err msg');
});
```

`expect(...).toThrow(...)` is able to match the thrown error message, but result on terminal shows the below error:

```
Chrome Headless 81.0.4044.138 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 30 SUCCESS (0.0 secs)
Chrome Headless 81.0.4044.138 (Windows 10): Executed 2 of 30 (1 FAILED) (0 secs)
Chrome Headless 81.0.4044.138 (Windows 10) tests for Test throws Error from react FAILED
        Uncaught Err msg thrown
```

Tests ran using **Karma, Jasmine**

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you expect some value you can assign your function to a variable and expect that variable to be something to be expected.

However, this is different when you expect `toThrow`. In this case, you should define your whole function inside `expect` only then you can verify the error.

```
expect(()=>{ throw new Error(); }).toThrow(); // --> PASSED
```

So in your case, your code should be something like;

```
function Test() {
  if (true) { throw new Error('Err msg'); }
  return (<div> abc </div>);
}
// react.spec.js
it('throws Error', () => {
    expect(() => {
      Test();
    }).toThrow('Err msg');
  });

  it('throws Error from react', () => {
    expect(() => {
      ReactDOM.render(<Test />, 'root');
    }).toThrow('Err msg');
  });
```

Comment: Are you trying to test a function or a component output? @Anant_Kumar

Comment: Updated the question for better description.
Problem is when functional react component is rendered.

Comment: I updated my answer,  If I understand your question, the answer would be something like this.

Comment: The way we are writing tests is fine, it has something to do with `ReactDOM.render()`